# Operation not permitted when opening Excel File on Mac

Tags: excel, powershell, permissions, file-permissions

I have a program that fetches the prices of my coins.

I'm trying to inject the prices into my excel file and to open it when running my code, but when I run the code it seems retrieve and update the previous price from the excel, but it won't open my excel file and gives the error

> **`Start-Process: /Users/User_Name/.local/share/powershell/Modules/ImportExcel/7.1.1/Public/Close-ExcelPackage.ps1:31.                                                   {Start-Process -FilePath $SaveAs }| Operation not permitted`**

Here is some of the code :

```
$file = '/Users/schyvensjim/Documents/Dev/CryptoScript/CoinBag.xlsx'
$xlsx = Open-ExcelPackage -Path $file

foreach($key in $shizzlebag.Keys) {

$coin = $shizzlebag[$key]

if($key -in $shizzlebagUNI.Keys) {
    $price = Get-UniPrice -id $shizzlebagUNI[$key].pool
} else {
    $price = Get-Price -id $coin.id -cur $coin.cur
  }

  $sheet = $xlsx.Workbook.Worksheets["Total USD"]
  $val = [decimal]$sheet.Cells[$coin.cell].Value
  $color = 'DarkGreen'

  if($val -gt $price) {
      $color = 'DarkRed'
  }

  $diff = $price - $val
  $change = '0'
  if([boolean]$val) {
      $change = ($diff / $val) * 100
  }

  "[{0}]`t{1}`t{2:n2}%" -f $key, $diff, $change | Write-Host -BackgroundColor $color

  $sheet.Cells[$coin.cell].Value = $price
}
Close-ExcelPackage -ExcelPackage $xlsx -Show
```

here is the Close-ExcelPackage function that got an error

```
function Close-ExcelPackage {
[CmdLetBinding()]
[Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("PSAvoidUsingPlainTextForPassword","")]
param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage]$ExcelPackage,
    [switch]$Show,
    [Switch]$NoSave,
    $SaveAs,
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]$Password,
    [switch]$Calculate
)
if ( $NoSave)      {$ExcelPackage.Dispose()}
else {
    if ($Calculate) {
        try   { [OfficeOpenXml.CalculationExtension]::Calculate($ExcelPackage.Workbook) }
        catch { Write-Warning "One or more errors occured while calculating, save will continue, but there may be errors in the workbook."}
    }
    if ($SaveAs) {
        $SaveAs = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($SaveAs)
        if ($Password) {$ExcelPackage.SaveAs( $SaveAs, $Password ) }
        else           {$ExcelPackage.SaveAs( $SaveAs)}
    }
    else         {
        if ($Password) {$ExcelPackage.Save($Password) }
        else           {$ExcelPackage.Save()          }
        $SaveAs = $ExcelPackage.File.FullName
    }
    $ExcelPackage.Dispose()
    if ($Show)   {Start-Process -FilePath $SaveAs }
}
```

}

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "it seems to look at the previous price and logs the changes" and without knowing the data involved we won't be able to help, but if you want help with troubleshooting the `Start-Process` error, please update your question to show the value of `$SaveAs`  and the _full_ error message you're getting. Generally, please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What version of `ImportExcel` are you using?  There might be a module update to help.  [You can check here](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel#whats-new-711).  If necessary, [you can post ImportExcel issues here](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues).

Comment: i updated the question i hope it is clearer, i'm using version 7.1.1 i think its the latest